# How to use an element of an array as an argument of indexOf method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two arrays of values. I want to use the elements of one array to be the argument of an `indexOf` function. But I get a `-1` (meaning value not found) even when I know the value exists in the array.

I have tested this by hard coding the value in the argument of `indexOf` so I know in this case that my problem is with `cur_data` variable. When I hard code the `cur_data[x]` with `'xyz'` the `indexOf` returns correct index however when I use the array value `[xyz]` it returns `-1`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function iterateSheets() {
  var price_data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Nttb7XqUlZwGtmwbcRc3QkY3f2rxx7XdsdEU3cK4K4').getSheetByName('price').getRange("A2:A353").getValues()
  var price_data2 = price_data.map(function(r) {
    return r[0];
  });
  var test = new Array(30)
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18qFvVMVEE1k5DWUYaSezKeobcLr8I4oAmHLUpd_X99k');
  var allShts = ts.getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) //allShts.length   //need to add in code to make sure tab is one of the fcst tabs  
  {
    var cur_data = allShts[i].getRange("B8").getValues()
    if (allShts[i].getName() == "July" || allShts[i].getName() ==
      "Aug" || allShts[i].getName() == "Sept") {

      for (var x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
        Logger.log(cur_data[x])
        Logger.log(price_data2.indexOf(cur_data[x]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please share your spreadsheet, or at least share some data in a spreadsheet so we can reproduce your errors. Would you also include the Execution Transcript.

Comment: Btw, could you please also clarify if the `cur_data[x]` is an instance of `Array` or not (nevermind, it is an instance of `Array` judging from code)? Seems like the problem is due to `getValues()` method always returning a 2D `Array` and, since object-to-object direct comparison always returns `false` and `indexOf()` [uses strict comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description) to find values, your `{Array}.indexOf({Array})` always results in `-1`.

Comment: You used `getValues`, so describe `cur_data` with the full 2D array address. This worked for me . `var c = price_data2.indexOf(cur_data[0][0]);` `Logger.log("c = "+c);'

Answer (score 2):

**2D Array of values**

`getValues()` method returns a two-dimensional `Array` of values from the `Range` that should be accessed via the `values[row][column]` schema. The `for` loop only increments the first dimension, that is, rows, and never accesses the value via column reference. Thus, you end up passing an `Array` instance to the `indexOf()` method.

**Modification**

You can add a second `for` loop to iterate over each of the elements of the `Array` of values, plus modify the first loop to make it more flexible just in case you ever need to loop over multiple rows:

```
for (var x = 0; x < cur_data.length; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < cur_data[x].length; y++) {
    Logger.log(cur_data[x][y])
    Logger.log(price_data2.indexOf(cur_data[x][y]));    
  }
}
```

**Comparison**

`indexOf()` method performs search via the *strict equality comparison* and here is where the fun part starts. As `Array` instances are also `Object`s, meaning the same rules of comparison that apply to objects apply to them. This means that *no two objects are equal* (take a look at the [comparison result table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#A_model_for_understanding_equality_comparisons)).

**Useful links**

1. `getValues()` [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
2. `indexOf()` MDN [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description);
3. Equality comparisons [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness);

Comment: This would be more helpful if you were to add a line showing "exactly" how the OP should write the indexof code. Such as "use:`price_data2.indexOf(cur_data[0][0]);`"